# IIS - Capturar usuário logado na maquina sem usar autenticação do Windows

Tags: c#, iis

Tenho um site que utiliza o usuário logado no computador para validar quais funcionalidades ele terá acesso dentro do site.
Para capturar o usuário logado na maquina estou usando o código abaixo, precisei alterar a autenticação do IIS para Windows Authentication, porém ele fica solicitando usuário e senha ao acessar pela primeira vez o site.

```
string userNameWindows = this.Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

Como faço para capturar o usuário logado na maquina sem solicitar login/senha no primeiro acesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso queira verificar o usuário do Windows com Forms Authentication, você pode utilizar este código:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Tostring()
```

Porém não é seguro. Facilmente o valor desta método irá de ser NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM ou o usuário configurado para rodar a aplicação no IIS. Isso ocorre pela autenticação estar com a propriedade impersonate habilitada.

Tente também este código:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal user;
user = new WindowsPrincipal(this.Request.LogonUserIdentity);
this.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Impersonate();
user_name = user_name.Substring(user_name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Caso nenhum dos casos te ajude, de uma olhada neste link em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184685/how-do-i-get-the-currently-loggedin-windows-account-from-an-asp-net-page

Comment: Felipe, tentei utilizar os métodos que você sugeriu porém não obtive sucesso. Caso eu utilize o Forms Authentication é apresentada a mensagem : 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. Ao utilizar o outro método o mesmo ainda solicita Login/Senha no primeiro acesso, sendo que deveria captar o usuário logado na máquina.

Comment: Victor, dei uma pesquisada e encontrei alguns pontos a serem analisados:
* Verificar se a autenticação de acesso anônimo ao IIS está desabilitada. 
* Servidor web deve estar no mesmo domínio de rede da máquina cliente, caso não esteja, deve haver uma relação de confiança entre os servidores para esta delegação de autenticação.
* Verificar se as definições do navegador permitem logon automático:  Ferramentas > Opções de internet > Segurança(Aba) > Nível Personalizado(botão) > Logon > Logon automático com o nome de usuário e senha atuais.

Comment: Felipe muito obrigado, finalmente consegui. .As configurações do IIS estavam corretas, o que estava impactando no problema eram as configurações do navegador que solicitavam login e senha ao entrar no SIte.